# ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit Slideshow Alternative

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've been using the ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit Slideshow extender and while it works, I'm not totally satisfied with it as it has problems handling multiple slideshows on one page and the fade is choppy.  Anyone suggest any alternatives?

**Edit**

Just curious also.  What is the general opinion of the Slideshow extender? Just wondering if I'm not the only one who's having minor problems with it.

Comment: I personally find it limiting and not as flexible as the jQuery options. The whole idea of controls encapsulating client-side events doesn't really work in ASP.NET - it's clunky and out-of-step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of jQuery based slideshow / galleries - you can find a list of [some of the best ones here](http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/03/15-amazing-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins-and-tutorials/). You can usually just write the HTML out in a Repeater and then add the javascript call by registering a client script.